# Having problems utilizing multiple filters for a Get-ADComputers command

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get multiple filters to work getting a list of users' computers. My conditions are:

- have logged in within the last 30 days
- excluding any server operating
- systems excluding servers that start with "Rose"
- aren't disabled

It seems to work filtering out everything except the computer names that start with "Rose". The format is the same for all conditions. The $time has a get-date.adddays(-30) already loaded. Here's my 1-liner:

```
Get-adcomputer -filter "OperatingSystem -notlike '*server*'" -properties * |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -gt $time -and ($_.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($_.name -ne 'Rose*')} |select name,lastlogondate,PrimaryGroup |Export-Csv C:\Users.csv
```

I tried to load the -filter property with my conditions but I couldn't get more than 1 filter to work, so I moved them to the where-object section.

Comment: You need to use `-like` or `-match` if you want to use wildcards.

Comment: I needed to use -notlike but yeah, that was the issue. Thanks! Make that a reply and not a comment so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh, yes you are correct ^^  glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `-ne` does not support wildcards. From the [about_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) help page:

> The comparison operators also include operators that find or replace
> patterns in text. The (-match, -notmatch, -replace) operators use
> regular expressions, and (-like, -notlike) use wildcards *.

You should be able to use `-notlike` or `-notmatch` instead.